# Handling of URLs in AEM content as a service

Tags: aem

When using AEM content as a service with Java models, you'd need to use the [JSON exporter](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/release-notes/json-exporter-dev-fp.html) to create JSON from a model when a resource is called with .model.json . How to deal with mapping links to other resources / pages in this context? After all, they need to be passed through [ResourceResolver.map(request, path)](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling10/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html#map-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-java.lang.String-) somewhere, and I'd hate to do that explicitly in the model whenever there is a link.